# Let $y'' + p(x)y' + q(x)y = 0$ , where $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are continuous. Prove that the zeroes of $y$ are isolated.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $p$ and $q$ be continuous, and let $y$ be any solution of $y′′(x) + p(x)y′(x) + q(x)y(x) = 0$ that is not identically zero. Then zeroes of $y$ are isolated, in the precise sense that for any $x_0$ with $y(x_0) = 0$, there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $y$ has only one zero for $x \in (x_0 −\varepsilon , x_0 +\varepsilon)$.
>
> **Hint**: argue that $y'(x_0) \neq 0$ and use the remainder theorem.

So far I know that R(remainder) = y(x) - P (rest of the taylor series), so y(x) = R + P.

Comment: Hi @zoneator. Welcome! You might find [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) helpful. Also, please show your working so far :)

Comment: Yiorgolos, we should prove that the derivative at x_0 is not equal to zero in the neighborhood of (x_0−ε,x_0+ε).

Answer (score 2):

Here we shall be using the fact that if $p,q\in C(I)$ continuous and $x_0\in I$, then the initial value problem, 
$$
y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0, \quad y(x_0)=a,\,\,y'(x_0)=b,
$$
has a unique solution $\psi : I\to\mathbb R$.

Assume now that the zeros of a solution $\varphi$ of  $$y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$$ have a limit point $x^*\in I$. Then $\varphi(x^*)=0$ by continuity of $\varphi$, and $\varphi'(x^*)=0$, since, if $x_n\to x^*$, is a sequence of zeros of $\varphi$, then
$$
0=\frac{\varphi(x_n)-\varphi(x^*)}{x_n-x^*}\to \varphi'(x_0).
$$ 
Therefore, $\varphi$ satisfies the initial value problem
$$
y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0, \quad y(x^*)=0,\,\,y'(x^*)=0,
$$
which has one and only one solution: the identically zero one.

Comment: Yiorgolos, we should prove that the derivative at x_0 is not equal to zero in the neighborhood of (x_0−ε,x_0+ε).

Comment: I showed above that if the zeros of $\psi$ have a limit point in $I$, then $\psi$ is identically zero.

Comment: However, the problem stated that ψ is not identically zero.

Comment: Exactly, it is impossible for the zeros a non identically zero solution to have a limit point, because if they had a limit point, then the solution would have to be identically zero, as I have shown. Are you familiar with "proof by contradiction"?

Comment: Hi Yirogolos, I should have made the problem more explicit. The main problem stated that The function x^2sin(1/x) has infinitely many zeroes in any neighborhood of the origin. This cannot happen for the solutions of differential equations we are studying.  ----> Main Problem: (Theorem) Let p and q be continuous, and let y be any solution of y′′(x) + p(x)y′(x) + q(x)y(x) = 0 that is not identically zero. Then zeroes of y are isolated, in the precise sense that for any x0 with y(x0) = 0, there exists ε > 0 such that y has only one zero for x ∈ (x0 −ε,x0 +ε).
Prove this theorem.

Comment: By the way, according to the hint you should argue that $y'(x)$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$. This means that, assuming this you shall arrive to a contradiction.

Comment: It is an interesting question. You should post it as a separate question!