# The zero of a nontrivial solution of Sturm Liouville problem is isolated and vanishes

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

I read Coddington, theory of ordinary differential equations. And there is a statement that

"A zero of a nontrivial solution of
$$
(p(t)x(t)')'+g(t)x(t)=0,\quad p(t)>0,\quad p, p', g\in \mathcal{C}(a,b).
$$
is isolated. Indeed, let the solution $\phi$ vanishes at $t_0.$ Then $\phi'(t_0)\neq 0$, for otherwise $\phi(t):=0.$ This proves that $t_0$ is an isolated zero."

I think that if zeros are discrete, then zeros are isolated, but I don't know how to start.

Please give me any hint.

Comment: You have a typo. It cannot be $\phi(t_0)\ne 0$. Surely you meant $\phi'(t_0)\ne 0$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thanks, my fault.

Comment: If $t_0 \in (a,b)$ is an accumulation point of zeros of a solution $x$, then $x(t_0)=x'(t_0)=0$ which yields $x(t)=0$ on $(a,b)$ by unique solvability of initial value problems.

Comment: See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674035/let-y-pxy-qxy-0-where-px-and-qx-are-continuous-prove-t

Comment: @Gred Oh, I see why the derivative of an accumulation zero is zero. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Gred Can I have a conclusion that if $f(x)$ is a unique nontrivial solution of ODE, then its zeros are isolated?

Comment: Yes, the argument above shows that the zeros of a nontrivial solution are isolated in $(a,b)$. Of course $a$ or $b$ can be an accumulation point of zeros. You can consider the same problem on a closed interval $[a,b]$. Then also $a$ and $b$ cannot be accumulation points of zeros, with the same proof. In that case the solution only has a finite number of zeros.